# Set query parameter from a cell in a data grid view

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, parameter-passing

I have a DataGrid view, if I select a certain cell I want to pass the value of a different cell (same row different column) to be used as a parameter in a query function.

**GridView**

[image: GridView]

So in the image sample if I select the highlighted cell then I want to pass the value in the "ITEMNUM" column of the same row. I have a separate Sub that is being called and within that sub I want to set a Parameter equal to the ITEMNUM cell.

I tied something like this in my Private sub but could not figure it out

```vb
SQl.AddParam("@Loggb", CrabDetails.dgvCurrentInv.Rows[crabdetails.dvgcurrentinv.CurrentRow.Index].cells[2].Value.ToString())
```

Comment: Look at this and think about what it's doing: `CrabDetails.dgvCurrentInv.Rows[crabdetails.dvgcurrentinv.CurrentRow.Index]`. It gets the current row, gets the index of that row, then gets the row at that index. Does that really make sense? That's like choosing a person from a crowd, asking them their name and then calling out that name and asking the person with that name to come forward. If you did that, would you be shocked that the person you just asked their name stepped forward? You've already got the current row. Why would you get its index and then get the same row by that index?

Comment: Think about the logic first and then write code to implement that logic. That's what you should do EVERY time. If you are showing us code without explaining the specific logic you think that code is supposed to implement, you're doing it backwards. When EXACTLY do you want this to happen? The "when" tells you what event you should be handling. Read the documentation for the `DataGridView` class to see what events it has and which one is raised when you want to do this task. You'll almost certainly find that that event provides you with the index of the relevant row.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [How to: Bind data to the Windows Forms DataGridView control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)